# javascript regex matching periods preceded by spaces/"&nbsp;"

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse a big HTML string so I can find all instances of a period that is preceded by any number of spaces (" ") or non breaking spaces (" ").  Then I want to replace all those instances with the spaces stripped out.

So far I have tried:

```
var ptn = "/(&nbsp;| )+[.]";
```

and many other variants, but none of them match correctly.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? `replace(/(&nbsp;| )+(\.)/g, "$2")`

The `$2` preserves the second match (e.g. the period).

Since we know it's always a period, you could also do the more simplistic:

`replace(/(&nbsp;| )+\./g, ".")`

Comment: Thanks! this is perfect.  good lesson on match capturing too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this regex:

```
var repl = html.replace(/(\s|&nbsp;)+\./g, '.');
```